# How do I rename & delete multiple keys in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, charts, highcharts

I am trying to build a pie chart in react js which uses highcharts (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/) is accepting only the following format for pie chart data (or maybe I'm wrong): Sample Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/react_user1/e9cbsrdL/1/

```
data: [
      {name: 'abc', y: 10},
      {name: 'def', y: 90}
]
```

The data I get from my API looks something like this:

```
const counts:[
{
"id": "all",
"type": "all",
"count": 1403
},
{
"id": "bad",
"type": "bad",
"count": 0
},
{
"id": "failed",
"category": false,
"type": "failed",
"count": 58
},
{
"id": "changed",
"category": true,
"type": "changed",
"count": 123
}
```

So I am trying to achieve three things here:

```
1. Remove the first {}, with the "id": "all"
2. Rename the key: "id" to name & "count" to y
3. Remove the keys: "type" & "category" & their data
```

Thanks for any help you could provide, even a partial answer that can help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combination.

With `filter()` you can remove the value what you don't need - in your case `all` - then with `map()` you can create a new structure for you array.

From the documentations - link mentioned above:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Just like this:

```js
const counts = [
  {
  "id": "all",
  "type": "all",
  "count": 1403
  },
  {
  "id": "bad",
  "type": "bad",
  "count": 0
  },
  {
  "id": "failed",
  "category": false,
  "type": "failed",
  "count": 58
  },
  {
  "id": "changed",
  "category": true,
  "type": "changed",
  "count": 123
  }
];

const result = counts.filter(f => f.id !== 'all')
                     .map(e => ({ name: e.id, y: e.count }));

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: updated on top of original fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/9361zgmh/](https://jsfiddle.net/9361zgmh/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide data as an array of arrays:

```
series: [{
    data: (() => counts.map(
        item => [item.id, item.count]
    ))()
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/op4s13dm/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  renderarrayobjects = () => {
return this.state.arrayname.map((Arrayelement, Indexvalue) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.btnColor}>
      <Text style={styles.tagtext}>{Arrayelement}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        Indexvalue={Indexvalue}
        onPress={() => {
          this.remove(Arrayelement);
        }}>
        <Image style={styles.editskill} source={deletarray} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}); };
```

The index value is the Index value.
   this will render a list of Array items  and we add an image that will be pressed to delete array the cross image will appear after every element of an array

```
  removePeople(Arrayelement) {
var array = [...this.state.Arrayelement];
var index = array.indexOf(Arrayelement);
if (index !== -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({Arrayelement: array});
}  }
```

this method will delete array objects.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts